# How to select an image from a popup list for use in a form

Tags: php, image, file, select, upload

I have a form to create an article but want the user to be able to select an image from a popup image list.

1. I added it and works fine for article EDIT where the article ID is know (post ID to the popup form that then update the database with the selected image url where article id = XXX)
2. The problem is NEW articles where the article id not yet exist before submission of form so how can I have the same functionality with new articles?

The goal is that people can EITHER select and upload their own image or otherwise choose from images that we already added to a list of images

Comment: put your code in here no one can understand how you want your code work

Comment: The is no code and no PHP code can do it. I am fairly okay with PHP but this would need ajax or javascript and I have very limited knowledge of it. Something that pass the selected image from a popup list, to the form before submit

Comment: Maybe php can do it. Select image from popup, put into session, submit form, get id, check if image url exist in session and if yes, update the db with the image url. So I might get this to work but maybe someone with better knowledge have other solution

Answer (score 0):

1. Add image: select an image and show it using a common attribute that you can use with jQuery later, on save button of popup get the image from popup and set to your input and save the form.
2. Edit Image: show image with id of article, follow the same process and save the form with id

Comment: Its not about the image, its about the article with optional selection of local image almost like selection of an emoji or emoticon but obviously full picture size.

Answer (score 0):

May it help u

```
if(!empty($id)){
//form to be update
}else{
//new form
}
```